# What is the catch in Money Market Funds ( core account)?

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds, online-banking, money-market

I see some of the money market Funds are yielding higher than the online-banks

1. Schwab Value Advantage Money Fund® Investor Shares ([SWVXX](https://www.schwabassetmanagement.com/products/swvxx)) is yielding 4.47%
   [image: swvxx]
2. FIDELITY GOVERNMENT MONEY MARKET ( [SPAXX](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/composition/31617H102) ) is yielding 3.96%
   [image: SPAXX]
3. Fidelity® Treasury Money Market Fund ([FZFXX](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/composition/316341304) ) is yielding 3.96%
   [image: FZFXX]

So my question is how these Money market fund are able to give such higher rate while none of the internet banks could match that and what could be the cons of putting money in these Money Market Funds ?

Answer (score 1):

Cut the middle man and invest in the money market yourself. What do you think banks are going to do with your short term deposit funds? The exact same thing, just take more than the 0.34% expense ratio that the Schwab fund has because why not?

In reality, the banks have much higher overhead than funds. They need to maintain branches, websites, personnel, provide customer support, deal with other activities, etc.

Comment: Money market accounts predate money market mutual funds, I believe...? (Though that might just be my awareness of them.)

Comment: @keshlam and...?

Comment: Just observation that the latter are effectively a discounted version of the former, rather than the former being a surcharge on the latter.

Comment: @littleadv actually I was looking to find what are the pros of online banking if brokerage money market funds are offering better rates.

Comment: @puzzled FDIC insurance

Comment: @littleadv thanks, I am surprised that swvxx has $110 billion , SPAXX has $245B and FZFXX has $33 B and is not FDIC insured and whoever (certainly not a few people) has put that much money are not worried about lack of FDIC insurance. I am slightly concerned

Answer (score 1):

With terms like 'Government' and 'Treasury' those funds mostly hold US Treasury products.

A quick check of Treasury Direct [recent auctions](https://treasurydirect.gov/auctions/announcements-data-results/) on Feb 15, 2023 shows:

| T-Bill | Issue Date | Investment Rate (coupon yield) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13-Week | 2/16/2023 | 4.802% |
| 26-Week | 2/16/2023 | 5.030% |
| 4-Week | 2/14/2023 | 4.599% |
| 8-Week | 2/14/2023 | 4.698% |

Which shows what those funds themselves (approximately) would be getting in the Treasury market. The difference between what the US Treasury is offering and funds are offering involves convenience by not restricting you to the purchase/sale time requirement and of course their overhead for providing such service.

If you have the patience you can buy directly via [Treasury Direct](https://treasurydirect.gov/) subject to their limitations, i.e. T-Bill purchases (retail non-auction) are typically on a once per week schedule, can't sell until term, etc.

Comment: thanks TreasuryDirect does not provide joint accounts and also does not have nomination feature

Comment: I was looking to find what are the pros of online banking if brokerage money market funds are offering better rates